# Windows 10 Startmenu Layout Baseline, tile missing

Tags: powershell, sccm, baseline, startmenu

I have created a baseline for my windows 10 deployments which sets the StartMenu to a default layout. (I had to make it a baseline due to some internal politics so don't ask :-) .)

This baseline creates a XML file with the data captured from a previous Startmenu export via Powershell. The script works and does what its supposed to do without issue. But when I log on with a new account the start menu is missing the IE tile. The script creates the missing shortcut at "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs" as I have read on a few other pages is needed. But that fix does not appear to be working for me.

This script also removes the windows 10 welcome video for new users.

This is the script:

```
$key = "\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"
$filecontent = @"
<LayoutModificationTemplate Version="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification">
  <LayoutOptions StartTileGroupCellWidth="6" />
  <DefaultLayoutOverride>
    <StartLayoutCollection>
      <defaultlayout:StartLayout GroupCellWidth="6" xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout">
        <start:Group Name="General Apps" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout">
          <start:Tile Size="1x1" Column="2" Row="1" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge" />
          <start:Tile Size="1x1" Column="3" Row="1" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy!CortanaUI" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.SoftwareCenter.DesktopToasts" />
          <start:Tile Size="1x1" Column="4" Row="1" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="4" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="{1AC14E77-02E7-4E5D-B744-2EB1AE5198B7}\SnippingTool.exe" />
          <start:Tile Size="1x1" Column="5" Row="0" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.People_8wekyb3d8bbwe!x4c7a3b7dy2188y46d4ya362y19ac5a5805e5x" />
          <start:Tile Size="1x1" Column="3" Row="0" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.InternetExplorer.Default" />
        </start:Group>
        <start:Group Name="" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout">
          <start:Tile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" />
          <start:Tile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.BingNews_8wekyb3d8bbwe!AppexNews" />
        </start:Group>
        <start:Group Name="Remote Tools" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout">
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.Windows.RemoteDesktop" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="Juniper.Junos Pulse.UserInterface" />
        </start:Group>
        <start:Group Name="" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout">
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.Office.OUTLOOK.EXE.15" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.Office.WINWORD.EXE.15" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="4" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.Office.EXCEL.EXE.15" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="2" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.Office.lync.exe.15" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="2" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.Office.ONENOTE.EXE.15" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="4" Row="2" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.Office.POWERPNT.EXE.15" />
        </start:Group>
      </defaultlayout:StartLayout>
    </StartLayoutCollection>
  </DefaultLayoutOverride>
</LayoutModificationTemplate>
"@

<# Remove Weclome Video #>

$res =  Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE$key -name EnableFirstLogonAnimation -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if (-not $res) 
    {New-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE$key -name EnableFirstLogonAnimation -value "0" -PropertyType "DWord"} 
else 
    {Set-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE$key -name EnableFirstLogonAnimation -value "0"}

<# Load XML Data #>
New-Item $env:ProgramData\testing\menulayout -ItemType directory
echo $filecontent |out-file $env:ProgramData\lmco\menulayout\LayoutModification.xml
Import-StartLayout -LayoutPath $env:ProgramData\lmco\menulayout\LayoutModification.xml -MountPath $env:SystemDrive\

<# Add IE Shorcut #>
$TargetFile = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
$ShortcutFile = "$env:ALLUSERSPROFILE\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Internet Explorer 11.lnk"
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetFile
$Shortcut.Save()

<# Cleanup #>
Remove-Item $env:ProgramData\testing\menulayout -Recurse -Force
```

Just wanted to know if someone could test this and see if they get the same result. Or even if anyone has found how to get the Missing Tiles to show.

If I set the tile to be a hard linked Shortcut using something like `<start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Internet Explorer.lnk" />` I end up breaking the startmenu for the user entirely.

I have also found that occasionally the Store Tile disappears from the start when I make changes to the IE line only so I am getting some strange results.

Also When I run an export-startlayout on the user just logged on I can see that the startmenu xml has no record of the missing tiles.

And I have also tried this with using the actual XML file to import and I get the same result running the 2 lines by hand.

**This is the Final version of the script. Ended up not using it sadly but it was nice to get it working.**

```
    <# Detect Office Version #>
    $office2013 = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    $office2016 = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    if($office2013) {$officeversion = "2013"}
    if($office2016) {$officeversion = "2016"}

    <# Reg Values #>
    $key = "\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"

    <# XML Data 2016 #>
    if ($officeversion -eq 2016) {
    $filecontent = @"
    <LayoutModificationTemplate Version="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification">
      <LayoutOptions StartTileGroupCellWidth="6" />
      <DefaultLayoutOverride>
        <StartLayoutCollection>
          <defaultlayout:StartLayout GroupCellWidth="6" xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout">
            <start:Group Name="General Apps" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout">
              <start:Tile Size="1x1" Column="2" Row="1" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge" />
              <start:Tile Size="1x1" Column="3" Row="1" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy!CortanaUI" />
              <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.SoftwareCenter.DesktopToasts" />
              <start:Tile Size="1x1" Column="4" Row="1" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" />
              <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="4" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="{1AC14E77-02E7-4E5D-B744-2EB1AE5198B7}\SnippingTool.exe" />
              <start:Tile Size="1x1" Column="5" Row="0" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.People_8wekyb3d8bbwe!x4c7a3b7dy2188y46d4ya362y19ac5a5805e5x" />
              <start:Tile Size="1x1" Column="3" Row="0" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" />
              <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="{6D809377-6AF0-444B-8957-A3773F02200E}\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" />
            </start:Group>
            <start:Group Name="" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout">
              <start:Tile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" />
              <start:Tile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.BingNews_8wekyb3d8bbwe!AppexNews" />
            </start:Group>
            <start:Group Name="Remote Tools" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout">
              <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.Windows.RemoteDesktop" />
              <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="Juniper.Junos Pulse.UserInterface" />
            </start:Group>
            <start:Group Name="" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout">
              <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.Office.OUTLOOK.EXE.15" />
              <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.Office.WINWORD.EXE.15" />
              <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="4" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.Office.EXCEL.EXE.15" />
              <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="2" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.Office.lync.exe.15" />
              <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="2" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.Office.ONENOTE.EXE.15" />
              <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="4" Row="2" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.Office.POWERPNT.EXE.15" />
            </start:Group>
          </defaultlayout:StartLayout>
        </StartLayoutCollection>
      </DefaultLayoutOverride>
    </LayoutModificationTemplate>
    "@
    }

    <# XML Data 2013 #>
    if ($officeversion -eq 2013) {
    $filecontent = @"
    <LayoutModificationTemplate Version="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification">
      <LayoutOptions StartTileGroupCellWidth="6" />
      <DefaultLayoutOverride>
        <StartLayoutCollection>
          <defaultlayout:StartLayout GroupCellWidth="6" xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout">
            <start:Group Name="General Apps" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout">
              <start:Tile Size="1x1" Column="2" Row="1" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge" />
              <start:Tile Size="1x1" Column="3" Row="1" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy!CortanaUI" />
              <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.SoftwareCenter.DesktopToasts" />
              <start:Tile Size="1x1" Column="4" Row="1" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" />
              <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="4" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="{1AC14E77-02E7-4E5D-B744-2EB1AE5198B7}\SnippingTool.exe" />
              <start:Tile Size="1x1" Column="5" Row="0" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.People_8wekyb3d8bbwe!x4c7a3b7dy2188y46d4ya362y19ac5a5805e5x" />
              <start:Tile Size="1x1" Column="3" Row="0" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" />
              <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="{6D809377-6AF0-444B-8957-A3773F02200E}\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" />
            </start:Group>
            <start:Group Name="" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout">
              <start:Tile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" />
              <start:Tile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.BingNews_8wekyb3d8bbwe!AppexNews" />
            </start:Group>
            <start:Group Name="Remote Tools" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout">
              <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.Windows.RemoteDesktop" />
              <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="Juniper.Junos Pulse.UserInterface" />
            </start:Group>
            <start:Group Name="" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout">
              <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.Office.OUTLOOK.EXE.15" />
              <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="{7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E}\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE" />
              <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="4" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="{7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E}\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE" />
              <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="2" DesktopApplicationID="{7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E}\Microsoft Office\Office15\lync.exe" />
              <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="4" Row="2" DesktopApplicationID="{7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E}\Microsoft Office\Office15\POWERPNT.EXE" />
              <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="2" DesktopApplicationID="{7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E}\Microsoft Office\Office15\ONENOTE.EXE" />
            </start:Group>
          </defaultlayout:StartLayout>
        </StartLayoutCollection>
      </DefaultLayoutOverride>
    </LayoutModificationTemplate>
    "@
    }

    <# Remove Weclome Video #>
    $res =  Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE$key -name EnableFirstLogonAnimation -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if (-not $res) 
        {New-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE$key -name EnableFirstLogonAnimation -value "0" -PropertyType "DWord"} 
    else 
        {Set-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE$key -name EnableFirstLogonAnimation -value "0"}

    <# Load XML Data #>
    $folderexist = (test-path $env:ProgramData\lmco\)
    if ($folderexist) 
        {New-Item $env:ProgramData\lmco\menulayout -ItemType directory}
    else
        {New-Item $env:ProgramData\LMCO\ -ItemType directory; New-Item $env:ProgramData\lmco\menulayout -ItemType directory}

    echo $filecontent |out-file $env:ProgramData\lmco\menulayout\LayoutModification.xml
    Import-StartLayout -LayoutPath $env:ProgramData\lmco\menulayout\LayoutModification.xml -MountPath $env:SystemDrive\

    <# Add IE Shorcut #>
    $TargetFile = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
    $ShortcutFile = "$env:ALLUSERSPROFILE\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Internet Explorer.lnk"
    $WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    $Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
    $Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetFile
    $Shortcut.Save()

    <# Cleanup #>
    Remove-Item $env:ProgramData\lmco\menulayout -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: I have also just confirmed that C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\LayoutModification.xml has the correct details that should be adding the IE link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some problems with IE in an application myself. As far as I found out Microsoft.InternetExplorer.Default does not seem to work and while some guides say Microsoft.Explorer.Default would work for IE this goes back to a typo in one of the original technet articles. I got it to work using a captured non-generic AppID which was

> {6D809377-6AF0-444B-8957-A3773F02200E}\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe

for 64Bit and

> {7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E}\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe

for 32Bit. You can get this ID with the Powershell Command 'Get-StartApps' for all possible programs so:

> Get-StartApps | where {$_.Name -ilike 'Internet Explorer*'}

To Get just IE if it ever breaks. As you can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882665%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) those are GUIDs for the ProgramFilesx64 and x86 Folder. There is also a generic one for ProgramFiles ({905E63B6-C1BF-494E-B29C-65B732D3D21A}) but as it is not listed with Get-StartApps it would probably not work.

However first this solution does not work across x64 and x86 windows with one file and second to me it seems like it might break at some point. This is not super likely as the IDs are present since vista and changing a GUID would break a lot of compatibility but still I'd rather not rely on a more obscure method as long as there is an alternative.

I therefore settled for the solution with the lnk file. If you do that however you cannot use the `DesktopApplicationID` anymore, but instead `DesktopApplicationLinkPath`. The correct syntax should be:

```
<start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Internet Explorer.lnk" />
```

Comment: Thanks Syberdoor, I tried the DesktopApplicationLinkPath option but that just killed the start menu again. But so far `{6D809377-6AF0-444B-8957-A3773F02200E}\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe` looks good we are only deploying x64 at my organization and if we have x86 its going to be less then 1% of the clients so we can manage that missing icon.  It might break with the next Major update but its better then a blank tile now at least.

Comment: Strange that the link did not work for you that way. I added the 32Bit ID as well as the Method to find those IDs.

Comment: Hi there - these Application IDs stay the same between deployments, right? Do you know under what circumstances they would change? (I just want to make sure there won't be any weird issues when imaging multiple machines.)

Comment: I don't have too much of experience with this but I did some tests and they always stayed the same. Also if you look at the way the appid is built it looks very much like a path where programfiles(x86/64) is replaced with some guid. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882665%28v=vs.100%29.aspx confirms this theory. Now no one can guarantee that ms will not change something but according to this article it exists since vista and was not changed so I think you will be fine. If you're worried you can also create the xml on the fly based on the get-startapps command, but you should be good.

Comment: I have added the final version of my script that detected 2013/2016 office.  It works as a base line as intended but I ended up not using it.  Can also be made into a SCCM package that can be deployed via TS.